# Why does my workflow not run on branch push, despite push on that branch and workflow triggers

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have tried a [workflow](https://github.com/keunes/AP-website-copy/actions/workflows/translation-updates-to-main-repo.yml) with the following triggers:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - contribute-pages/**
      - documentation-pages/**
      - general-pages/**
      - general-strings/**
```

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - translation-files
```

However, when the [Weblate bot](https://github.com/weblate) pushes changes to that very folder and branch ([example](https://github.com/keunes/AP-website-copy/commit/6113bdf47de660d55d45b56f9abde101c55d9535)) the action does not kick in. Why might that be the case?

I should note that the Workflow file lives in the 'main' branch, not the 'translation-files' branch it should be reacting to. But since the trigger mentions that translation-files branch I would expect that not to be a problem.

The action does run when initiated manually.

Comment: It can't work that way. You need to have workflow file on `translation-files` branch as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying frennky. Do you know why this is not possible? (I couldn't find anything in the docs, and why else would you specify the branch in the trigger… – though maybe I overlooked something)

Comment: I just created a workflow for the translation-files branch, and adapted it to the new situation. However, the workflow is not showing up in the Actions tab of the repo. So I can't check the logs/initiate it, and it probably doesn't work. Is it not possible to have a workflow in another branch than main/master?

Answer (score 0):

It can't work that way. You need to have workflow file on `translation-files` branch as well.

To answer your questions from comments:

> Do you know why this is not possible?

> Is it not possible to have a workflow in another branch than
> main/master?

You can have workflow in any branch. Your branching strategy is a bit out of the ordinary. You have `translation-files` branch which seems to be long lived branch that doesn't get updated by master, so it doesn't have your workflow and for that reason doesn't get triggered.

Github actions is obviously built around Github flow, and for that kind a flow it makes sense to have workflows on each branch. If you still don't understand why it is designed that way or don't know what Github flow is, you can start [here](https://githubflow.github.io/).